# Is there any reason not to allow access to all data from all partial view?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

Yep. This question came up looking at Code Igniter but it is not really related to code igniter due to the fact that every MVC php web app could hit the face on that.

Considering MVC as app design, let's imagine that a `view` is divided into `partial views`. By default `partial views` has its own data as `view` has its own. Now I was wondering: Is there any reason not to allow `partial views` to have access to `view`'s data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no OOP god but I have used the decorator pattern to build views (Rolled my own as I don't like the templates in codeigniter/zend etc).

In terms of constructing a page it is (in my opinion) essential that the partial views are able to communicate with parents - if a component of your partial view requires some external resource (like a specific javascript file) it SHOULD be able to tell the layout to include it in the head section of a page without having access itself to make that change.

So I suppose the partial view should NOT have access to the view but must communicate with it, otherwise you are building in a dependency for that partial to that view which may prevent one or both being utilised elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

partial view is for simplicity of developing individual module or component in the frontend, which is not supposed to need all global parameters.

For code usability and a little bit bandwidth, it's better to split apart the parameters being sent

If you really want all parmeters being passed, then just choose another view template instead of the partial one.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good idea to only provide the data to the View (or, in this case, Partial View) that it needs to properly render.

This forces developers to think a bit before modifying any component and prevents the mixing of responsibilities between Views/Partial Views. This also enhances re-usability since you won't run the risk of your Partial View requiring access to data that might not be present in every situation the Partial View is being used in.

Answer (score 0):

the Ruby on Rails - default answer is no. The partials can be considered as children of the corresponding view.

There could be some problems if your doing some asynchronous data editing - vodoo.

Other then that keep it simple and stupid.. The partial of a view knows what the view knows...